# Windows Server 2008 r2 + IIS7: .mp4 files can not be played

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, hosting, windows-server-2008-r2, vps

I have the strange trouble.Folder of web application in my server (IIS7.5, Windows Server 2008 R2). Web application has Video player.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                      <video src='<%# ResolveUrl(GetVideoHandler(Eval("id"))) %>' width="900" height="400" controls="" preload=""></video>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

It can play .mp4 on my local System, but it don't play on live server when i accessing a video on other system.i have a Value gettong in `ResolveUrl(GetVideoHandler(Eval("id")))` `VideoFolder/VideoName.mp4` for playing video. Its working fine on my loaclHost during developing but don't working when Im accessing it web link on other computer. Have anybody idea? Thanks.

Comment: what is the exact error code + message? could be anything. bad path, does not support byte-range requests.

Comment: Video Format or MIME Type is not supported will getting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the mime type to the server or web application web.config, (or in IIS under mime types).

```
 <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
 </staticContent>
```

Comment: Hi! Flavor, I try this too but still not working. dose i need to edit folder security property too?

Comment: That would usually 404 or 403 if permissions are incorrect, not warn about MIME type. You can try adding IIS_IUSRS and IUSR to execute/read in case

Comment: I save this video Url in database like this ~\VideoFolder\VideoName.mp4 and with code im filling the path in Video Player like this VideoFolder/VideoName.mp4 it working well on my local host but i don't know why it not working on from server side. i also thy this code which you suggest me to add in web.config and in iis too but still video is not loading.

Comment: can you access any type of file from the generated path?

Comment: Have you add MIME type on IIS? Do you use shared hosting? if yes, please ask your hosting provider to setup it for you.

Answer (score 2):

it's a quite a simple answer:
Windows server 2008 has no mpeg-4 multiplexer, so you cant see any mp4 on your machine with default configuration of your server.

you can notice that if you stand with your mouse cursor on a video file in your computer you will able to see basic file info like name and duration.

at your server you might find out that if you do the same on an mp4 media file you will not able to see this information...

the answer for that issue is to go to server manager under the administrative tools in your windows server 2008 r2 from the start menu.

from there you need to choose features in the left side.
after that you need to prees add features and select DESKTOP EXPERIENCE and install.

this is the primary thing you need do do for you machine to be able to read mp4 info.
after that you need to mime type for your mp4 media files.
install codecs.