# Video download from Azure Api Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have a hosted a azure api service and able to successfully upload the videos through my code under a folder "UserVideos" when i am trying to refer the link of uploaded video in video tag it is not working.

The video also does not get downloaded using this url in any browser.

http://abcorg.azurewebsites.net/UserVideos/VID20190605102000.mp4

Any help will really be appreciated

below is the way i have refereed the video url in video tag.

Comment: <video width="400" controls>
  <source src="http://abcorg.azurewebsites.net/UserVideos/VID20190605102000.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

Comment: Found the solution to this problem on another thread at StackOverflow. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274486/iis-returns-404-not-found-for-mp4-files

Comment: DNS lookup failed can you please confirm have you configured hostname settings properly? your naked  azure website is throwing an error