# IIS 7.0 MIME Type .MP4

Tags: iis, video, iis-7.5, mime-types, mp4

Working in IIS7.0(7.5.7600.16385) on Windows Server 2008 R2

Trying to get a video of the type .MP4 to play on a webpage.

IF the URL is specified using the actual server path, the video will play:

```
 \\myproductionserver\wwwroot\Video\Activevideos\videotestpage.html
```

This is true for our production and development servers.
However if i use the actual URL:

```
  http://example.com/Video/ActiveVideos/videotestpage.html
```

...it will not play

Per various information sources, I have added .MP4 as video/mp4 to my IIS MIME Types (via GUI).
Nothing works.
Thoughts on getting this to work?

==================
UPDATE:
I went to HTML5TEST.com and it says under the video section that MPEG 4 is not supported.  following some suggestions from this post for IE 9 [HTML5 - mp4 video does not play in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944679/html5-mp4-video-does-not-play-in-ie9)
I replaced my video tag with the one that shows "Your browser does not support the video tag."

When I ran my page, Your browser does not support the video tag. came up.
So...what is that telling me?  Especially since if I execute the url using the actual server paths, it works?

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by putting the following in the page:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" /
```

Comment: I was able to fix by adding mime type in web.config file as mentioned here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258125/windows-server-2008-r2-iis7-mp4-files-can-not-be-played

Answer (score -1):

You can add this code in the webconfig:

```
<remove fileExtension=".mp4v" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4v" mimeType="video/mp4v" />
```

After restart App pool and open you website or web app